# How to hide affiliate link?

Tags: php

I have domain   mydomain.com (my website)

I have partner link  partnerlink.com/something?partnerId (thirdparty provider)

Partner link opens destination.com (thirdparty website)

My problems:

1. When I try bit.ly and click it, I see redirections in browser: bit.ly/123 --> partnerlink.com/something?partnerId --> destination.com
2. When I try to use .htaccess redirect or header in php script, I also an see partner link in browser on slow internet connection.

I want to hide partner link. The scheme is:

> click on mydomain.com --> result is destination.com

user in this case don't see partner link in browser.

But such user click should count my provider partnerlink.com

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

The user's browser has to pass the affiliate id to the target. It will do so in a way that is visible to the user.

(As a general rule of thumb, being open about affiliations is a good idea. Efforts to hide them will hurt your visitors' trust in you when they fail.)

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't possible - the affiliate handler (which is the cause of the redirection) needs all of the information, otherwise you won't get credited for the click-through.

Hiding the nature of your affiliates is probably not a good thing anyway - especially now as tracking cookies are a big issue with "the authorities" (at least over here in Europe)